# How to optimize the multiplication of probability tables using dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary, probability, multiplication

I am having troubles implementing a multiplication of probability tables using dictionary in Python.
I really don't want the most optimized code, but the problem is that the implementation I did is so slow that can take hours for a simple sequence of multiplications.

Here is how it is currently.
A probability table is a dictionary where the keys are tuples of its configuration and the value is the probability value.
For example, consider multiplying two probability tables **P(A,B,C)** and **P(A,C,D)**, where **A**, **B**, **C**, and **D** are binary variables (say, with domain {*true*,*false*}).
First, both tables are represented by dictionaries:

```
P_ABC = { (false,false,true):  0.01,
          (false,true,false):  0.05,
          (true,false,false):  0.10,
          (false,true,true):   0.05,
          (true,true,false):   0.05,
          (true,false,true):   0.05,
          (true,true,true):    0.30,
          (false,false,false): 0.39 }

P_ACD = { (false,false,true):  0.01,
          (false,true,false):  0.05,
          (true,false,false):  0.10,
          (false,true,true):   0.05,
          (true,true,false):   0.05,
          (true,false,true):   0.05,
          (true,true,true):    0.30,
          (false,false,false): 0.39 }
```

Next, I save the indexes of common variables for both tables in a list:

```
matchingIndexes = [(0,0),(2,1)]
```

where the first value in a tuple is the first table and the second value the second table.
In our running example, this list can be interpreted as two variables are common to both tables, namely **A** and **C**.
**A** is in first position (index 0) in the first table, as well as in the second.
In the other hand, **C** is in the third position (index 2) in the first table, but in the second position (index 1) in the second table.

Given that, my next step is to perform the multiplication.
But I only multiply a row if they have the same domain values for all matching variables (columns of the table).
Follows my proposed algorithm:

```
results = []
for row1 in P_ABC:
            for row2 in P_ACD:
                flag = True
                for ind in matchingIndexes:
                    flag = flag and (row1[ind[0]] == row2[ind[1]])
                if flag:
                    mult = P_ABC[row1] * P_ACD[row2]
                    results.append( mult )
```

Like I said, this version is very slow.
Since all my code was done expecting the tables to be represented as the described dictionaries, I would put changing the way I represent the tables as last option.
But if it's the only way to optimize the multiplication of tables, I would consider it.

Does anyone can give me an insight on how to make this faster?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at some implementations, I understood that the best option of making this fast is using matrices.
Basically, we don't need to represent the rows of **P_ABC** and **P_ACD**, but only the probabilities values.
Then, the multiplication of tables can be done by multiplying the probabilities table in a certain mapped order.